# Custom Django-Allauth SignUp form not adding new users

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I tried to create a custom Signup Form with allauth but when I submit the form on the frontend it directs to the `success_url` and upon inspection in the admin panel a new user wasn't created.

```
# forms.py
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class SimpleSignupForm(SignupForm):
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), max_length=255, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), max_length=255, required=True)
    address = AddressField(required=True)
    type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserType.objects.all())

    def save(self, request):
        user = super(SimpleSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
        user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.type = self.cleaned_data['type']
        user.save()
        return user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        visibles = self.visible_fields()
        visibles[0].field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

```
# settings.py
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'my_app_path.forms.SimpleSignupForm'}
```

On the template file I made sure the `<form>` tag has `method='POST'` and that I included `{% csrf_token %}` in the form. The button is also a a `submit` type. I've also made sure `{{ form.as_p }}` has all the required fields when submitting. There are no errors or warnings popping up anywhere.

Comment: Have you solved this ? Inside the `save` method, output to a log file the `cleaned_data` to make sure this method is being called.

Comment: I created a completely new project trying to create a custom sign up form that works and it works in the new project, I did a thorough comparison between the two projects line for line and nothing was different. I'm assuming it might have been a broken project setup beyond django framework. Honestly does not make sense what happened

Comment: I see. You can always automate diffs with git (or diff). The database contents were coherent between versions too ? Anyway it's something out of the way now then.

Comment: I used Pycharm's compare two files feature. But it's good to know git has that feature :) will remember it for next time

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I will recommend you use Signup method instead of Save

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'First Names'
    self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Last Names'

def signup(self, request, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.save()
```